# copy a local git branch via ansible to remote?

Tags: git, ansible

I have a local `git` repo on my workstation that I'd like to push (using a specific branch) to a remote host via `ansible`. Is there a way to do this without needing to use a repo server or extra hackery with `synchronize` to get the right branch selected on the remote?

This is the shell command I use to do it right now. The source repo is on localhost under "/usr/src/bin"

```
pushd /usr/src/bin && git checkout ${some_branch} && rsync  -av * myremote:/tmp/bin/ --delete-after --exclude=.git && popd
```

I haven't been able to find the right `ansible` yaml to get it working though. This is what I'm working with right now.

```
- name: copy defined git branch to remote
  when:
    - remote_git_branch is defined
  git:
    repo: "/usr/src/bin/"
    dest: /tmp/bin/
    version: "{{ remote_git_branch }}"
```

Comment: I don't have the specifics to make this a proper answer, so here is an idea. Use the git module to make a local clone of the repo (maybe even a shallow clone). Then, use the copy module to send that directory over to the remote.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that if nothing else turns up.

Comment: What is the actual problem using `synchronize` when your original command line solution is already using rsync? Meanwhile, if I correctly understand what you are trying to do, a simple `git archive -o archive.tar.gz yourBranch` followed by `unarchive` (using the `copy` attribute) would probably be much more convenient and performant.

Comment: They way I do it now, every branch is available on the remote since the entire directory is being transferred. I'd rather only have the current branch transferred, or a specific one. I could exclude `.git` I suppose, but then the remote directory doesn't appear to be transferred from a repo under revision control. Maybe I'm trying to be too careful.